# try block limits scope of const variable

Tags: c++, exception

When wrapping initializations of a constant I frequently run into scope issues

```
try {
  const int value = might_throw();
}
std::cout << value << "\n";  /* error, value out of scope */
```

Currently I use a temporary value as a workaround. Is there a better way to deal with `const` - `try {}` situations?

```
int tmp;  /* I'd rather have tmp const */
try {
  tmp = might_throw();
}
catch (...) {
  /* do something */
}
const int value = tmp;
```

Comment: What’s the reason for not using the variable in the try block?

Comment: The variable might be used in many lines following the try block. Are you saying I should enlarge my try block to enclose everything, even if that includes many lines of code that is only related by the use of the variable?

Comment: Not necessarily. I just wanted to get the (potentially) easiest solution out of the way. I do agree that it’s a problem in some situations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of your

```
int tmp;  /* I'd rather have tmp const */
try {
    tmp = might_throw();
}
catch (...) {
    /* do something */
}
const int value = tmp;
```

you can do this:

```
int int_value()
{
    try {
        return might_throw();
    }
    catch (...) {
        /* do something */
        return the_something_value;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int const value = int_value();
}
```

Or, in C++11 you can do

```
int main()
{
    int const value = []() -> int {
        try {
            return might_throw();
        }
        catch (...) {
            /* do something */
            return the_something_value;
        }
    } ();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To me this looks like a case for a function:

```
int const value = []()->int {
    try { return might_throw(); }
    catch (...) { return come_up_with_a_value_differently(); }
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
   const int value = might_throw();
   std::cout << value << '\n';
}
catch (...) {
   std::cout << "threw instead of giving me a value :(\n";
}
```

`try` is a scope block for a reason!

If you're doing far more than a `std::cout` with `value` then, yeah, it gets a bit messier. Then you have a choice of:

- dropping the `const`,
- encasing *all* logic that uses `value` in the `try`, or
- initialising a `const int` from the value returned by a function `int mightThrowWrapper(int default = 0)` that itself wraps try/catch and returns a default on throw. Then you've got your localised exception handling *and* `const`ness!